# Decoding of metdata of mp3 file in Android

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an mp3 file and I try to read metadata (METADATA_KEY_TITLE) of the mp3 file. The String chapterName is decoded somehow wrongly and instead of "Předmluva" I get "PĹ™edmluva" (or sometimes some Chinesse letters). Can you please heklp me? I have tried evertything but nothing helped.

```
import android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever

val mmr = MediaMetadataRetriever()
// getting chapter-name
var chapterName = mmr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE)
```

Comment: isnt' mmr.extractMetadata(int)?

Comment: No, still the same problem :(